# error connecting to mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

i ran into a weird problem when connecting to mysql using java.

i'm running xampp with tomcat

i tried connecting to mysql from java. on my machine it works fine, but on a friends machine i get an error: access denied for user 'tomcat'@'localhost'

thing is - i managed to connect with the exact same info using php.

the java code for the connection is:

```
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "mta_db";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "tomcat";
    String password = "tomcat";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        _conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

port is fine

any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: What does SHOW GRANTS say in mysql?

Comment: premissions are fine. i can connect through php with no problem. SHOW GRANTS returns 2 rows with GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION, GRANT PROXY ON "@" TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION. i tried user root also

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably on the MySQL side, that is, the `tomcat` user doesnt have privileges to connect from non-`localhost`.

For simplicities sake you can first create an account that is able to connect from anywhere, via the MySQL `GRANT` statement like so:

```
GRANT ALL ON mta_db.* to tomcat@'%' identified by 'yourpassword';
```

In this case the `%` is a wildcard for any host.

If you know the actual IPs of your connecting clients you can later crack it down, to be more security conscious.

Comment: does not work. it connects fine from PHP btw, and i checked the privileges